# map module not showing map in joomla 2.5 live site, but working in localhost.

Tags: google-maps, iframe, joomla2.5, jquery-dialog

I have installed a map module "Gmap direction" in joomla 2.5  to show direction between two places. this module is working fine in localhost. But in live site it doesn't show the map, the other contents of that module has displayed. 
The same issue happen for jquery dialog(working in local, but not in live).
Do i need to change any setting?

Comment: Check browser's console for errors?

Comment: Browser console status.  error1:  Blocked loading mixed active content: "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"                                      Error2:Blocked loading mixed active content "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"         Error3:ReferenceError: google is not defined...............                  Error1&2 repeated for 2 times.

Comment: https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js. Use https instead of http?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Use https instead of http?**

In include tags?

```
script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"
```

Comment: in another way, we can omit both http and https.                    script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js".  This one also working.